# iphone : how to solve this memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, instruments

How to solbe this memory leak ... I even release it at the end as in the pic but its still there. In if statment almost 10-15 condition its using like the given code... But at the end I release it.

[image]

```
LoginResponse *response = [[LoginResponse alloc] initWithMessageString: messageString];


ServerMessage *ackMessage = [[ServerMessage alloc] initWithMessageToAck:response];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SendMessageToServer" object:ackMessage];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginResponseReceived" object:response];
```

Comment: you release the string outside the `if` where you create it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're **not** releasing `messageString`. What you're doing is this:

```
// there's a messageString
if(...){
     NSString* messageString= [[NSString alloc] init ... ]
                                   // you're declaring new messageString, 
                                   // not related to the outer messageString
     ...
     // and you didn't release the inner messageString. 
     // The pointer messageString just goes away.
}
[messageString release]; // you're releasing outer messageString, not inner messageString.
```

Perform "Analyze" from XCode. (It's below the "build" menu item.) I think that should capture this problem of forgetting to release the inner `messageString`. Use "Analyze" before running Instruments.

Comment: Build and Analyze does complain about this kind of thing, but I'm not convinced that it should.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? I'm not talking about the hiding of the outer message string by the inner messageString; I was talking about the fact the OP didn't release the inner messageString. Well I didn't say that in my answer :p

Answer (score 0):

See if you are retaining it somewhere else in the code. If so, that might require an extra release. Also note that a method that you might be using passing `messageString` as argument might also be retaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to release the string inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb is that for every `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`, you need a `release` or `autorelease`. It seems that you are missing a `release`or `autorelease` somewhere.

By the way, you cam (and should) use Xcode's "Build and Analyze" to help find memory leaks before you even deploy to a testing device.